# Using "setlocal enabledelayedexpansion" in cmd prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Does `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` only work in a batch file? How can `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` be used in a cmd prompt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable delayed expansion in a command prompt with the command `cmd /V:ON`

From `cmd /?`:

```
/V:ON   Enable delayed environment variable expansion using ! as the
        delimiter. For example, /V:ON would allow !var! to expand the
        variable var at execution time.  The var syntax expands variables
        at input time, which is quite a different thing when inside of a FOR
        loop.
```

Comment: @user15964 - When you combine commands like that, they are all interpreted within the context of the current environment, so `command` is treated like it is still in the `/V:OFF` cmd prompt. A one-liner like you want is not possible.

Comment: I stand corrected. (To be fair, I can't imagine a single situation where I would ever be forced to use a one-liner.) The information about the environment not changing is still good, so I won't delete the comment.

Comment: @PetSerAl Are you sure? `cmd /v:on /c command` didn't works for me

Comment: @user15964 I type `set var=value&cmd /v:on /c echo !var!` in my `cmd` prompt, and I got `value` printed, as result.

Answer (score 1):

Learn by example: `Copy&Paste` from my CMD window:

```
==>echo !os! %pp%
!os! %pp%

==>cmd /E:ON /V:ON /K set "pp=yy" & set pp & echo !os! !pp!

==>echo !os! %pp%
Windows_NT yy

==>exit
Environment variable pp  not defined
!os! !pp!

==>cmd /E:ON /V:ON /K set "pp=yy" ^& set pp ^& echo !os! !pp!
pp=yy
Windows_NT yy

==>echo !os! %pp%
Windows_NT yy

==>exit

==>echo !os! %pp%
!os! %pp%

==>
```

Explanation:

- `echo !os! %pp%` returns `!os! %pp%` showing delayed expansion disabled and `pp` variable not defined in current CLI;
- `cmd /E:ON /V:ON /K set "pp=yy" & set pp & echo !os! !pp!` returns nothing,  new instance of the Windows command interpreter has delayed expansion enabled (see `echo !os! %pp%` output);
- `exit` returns result of `set pp & echo !os! !pp!` in a parent CLI instance: `Environment variable pp  not defined` and `!os! !pp!`;
- `cmd /E:ON /V:ON /K set "pp=yy" ^& set pp ^& echo !os! !pp!` returns `pp=yy` and `Windows_NT yy` in the new CLI instance (note all `&` escaped by `^`);
- `echo !os! %pp%` returns `Windows_NT yy` in the new CLI instance (it shows delayed expansion *enabled* and `pp` variable *defined* in the child CLI);
- `exit` to a parent  CLI instance;
- `echo !os! %pp%` returns `!os! %pp%` again.